# How to disable IPv6 on a particular network interface using Server Core?

Tags: networking, windows-server-core

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server Core machine and would like to disable IPv6 on one of its network adapters. Essentially *this* if there was a UI:

[image: Adapter properties]

Any ideas?

Comment: You can do it by unbinding the specific adapter.  I don't see a PS script for it, but it shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a script for that...now.

Replace Local Area Connection with the name of the adapter. This gets the GUID of that adapter and removes it from the value of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip6\Linkage\Bind` property (uses a temp variable).

PowerShell - Elevated privileges and might require a restart.

```
$UnbindID = $(Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_NetworkAdapter' | Where-Object {$_.NetConnectionID -eq 'Local Area Connection'}).GUID
$LinkageKey = $(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip6\Linkage').Bind | Select-String -Pattern $UnbindID -NotMatch -SimpleMatch
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip6\Linkage' -Name 'Bind' -Type MultiString -Value $LinkageKey
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is null.`. Here's what the [registry looks like](http://i.imgur.com/e66D9.png) at that path. Any ideas?

Comment: Odd.  I hate to ask the question, but are you sure it's not already disabled?  That key is the list of GUIDs for Network Adapters that "bind" to IPv6.  That is showing there are none.  Deeper into the registry we go!

Comment: Check the Export and Route keys (in that same spot in the registry) and see if that GUID appears.  If you're not sure which GUID, just type `$UnbindID` and it should output that value.  Let me know.

Comment: Rewind - there's something going wrong with the name of the adapter, but I don't know what. sconfig [shows this](http://i.imgur.com/ITWtU.png) and from PS [I see this](http://i.imgur.com/euwPr.png). So I changed the first line of the script to `$UnbindID = $(Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_NetworkAdapter' | Where-Object {$_.NetConnectionID -eq 'Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection'}).GUID` but no value is coming back.

Comment: Alright, let's try the non-scripting method.  Run `Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_NetworkAdapter' | Select-Object NetConnectionID,GUID`.  Look on the screen and find the correct GUID.

Next, we need to do some housekeeping.  Open regedit (just type `regedit` at prompt), browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip6\Linkage.  Open the value for Export and copy that.  Open the value for Bind (now empty) and paste it.  With that window still open, remove the line that references the same GUID that you want to remove.  Save.  Restart.  Report.

Answer (score 0):

Registry hack, unfortunately.  Really should be a `netsh` command, but consistency is not Redmond's forté. ([source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/cc987595.aspx))

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters`

Create DWORD: `DisabledComponents`

Set value to `0xffffffff`

Comment: My guess is that this will disable the entire IPv6 stack. Is there any way to disable it for a specific adapter?

Comment: @Alex This one's even worse.  Modify this multi-string value: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Linkage\Bind`, stripping out the line with the GUID for the network card you want to disable.  You can find the GUID in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards` - `Description` has a readable name, `ServiceName` has the GUID.